# Magento 2: Folder and file permissions

Tags: magento2, permissions, server-setup

For some reason, I'm having issues with a fresh install of M2, though, things seem to sort themselves out if I update the file and folder permissions on the server.

Unfortuntely, if I re-deploy the static content, or flush the cache, I need to re-update the folder permissions on the server.

Has anyone else experienced the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

You might be rebuilding static-content/flushing cache as root. Make a magento file owner user and chown the install to that user, in your apache group. Then do all your `bin/magento` tasks as that user.

Answer (score 0):

Try using magento default file/folder permissons:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; && find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \; && chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Comment: I can't use 770 and 660 on my server, as it shows that I don't have permission to view the site in the browser. Instead, I've been using 755 and 644, which shows the site but I then have to reset the permissions any time I make a change to the site.

Comment: This is from magento devdocs provide this command for set file folder permissions.

Comment: Magento is currently re implementing how we set file permissions in code. Until we change it though, you either have to use 770/660 or continue to reset permissions as you are doing now. Whenever Magento writes files, we set them with 770/660 permissions.